# no. of real solution of the equation $5\cdot 2^x+4\cdot 3^x = 3\cdot 4^x+2\cdot 5^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Total number of real solution of the equation $5\cdot 2^x+4\cdot 3^x = 3\cdot 4^x+2\cdot 5^x$

$\bf{My\; try::}$ Let $f(x) = 5\cdot 2^x+4\cdot 3^x - (3\cdot 4^x+2\cdot 5^x)\;,$

Then $f'(x) = 5\cdot 2^x\ln(2)+4\cdot 3^x\ln(3)-3\cdot 4^x\ln(2)-2\cdot 5^x\ln(2)$

Now I did not understand how can i proceed further,

Or can we solve it without using Derivative test, explain me

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hard to show that $x = 1$ is the only solution without using the derivative test.

Case I: $x > 1$.

Since $x-1 > 0$, we have $2^{x-1} < 5^{x-1}$. Multiply both sides by $10$ to get $5 \cdot 2^x < 2 \cdot 5^x$.

Similarly, we have $3^{x-1} < 4^{x-1}$. Multiply both sides by $12$ to get $4 \cdot 3^x < 3 \cdot 4^x$.

Adding the inequalities together yields $5 \cdot 2^x + 4 \cdot 3^x < 3 \cdot 4^x + 2 \cdot 5^x$.

Hence, there are no solutions in this case.

Case II: $x < 1$.

Since $x-1 < 0$, we have $2^{x-1} > 5^{x-1}$. Multiply both sides by $10$ to get $5 \cdot 2^x > 2 \cdot 5^x$.

Similarly, we have $3^{x-1} > 4^{x-1}$. Multiply both sides by $12$ to get $4 \cdot 3^x > 3 \cdot 4^x$.

Adding the inequalities together yields $5 \cdot 2^x + 4 \cdot 3^x > 3 \cdot 4^x + 2 \cdot 5^x$.

Hence, there are no solutions in this case.

Case III: $x = 1$.

Trivially, $x = 1$ is a solution since $5 \cdot 2^1 + 4 \cdot 3^1 = 22 = 3 \cdot 4^1 + 2 \cdot 5^1$.

Therefore, the only solution is $x = 1$.

Comment: ^Thanks for catching that.